# angularjs function called just after the first click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an issue with angularjs 1 and ionic is that I have a list of items , so I want to show the clicked item properties , so I tried to ways to save the id of the clicked item, but the same issue which is , just the first time after refreshing the page (while serving on laptop) I got the right clicked item properties , but if I clicked back and tried to click on another item i get the properties of the item i clicked first! why is that happening ? how can I fix this ? thank you

this is the service for storing and retrieving the id :

```
.service('eventID', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
 this.saveID = function(id) {
  $rootScope.ID = id;
}
this.getID = function() {
  return $rootScope.ID;
}
}]);
```

this is what's inside the first controller :

```
 $scope.setMaster = function(event) {
  $scope.selected = null;
  $scope.selected = event.id;
  eventID.saveID($scope.selected);
  $state.go('detail');
}
```

this is what's inside the second controller where i will get the id of the selected item :

```
$scope.selected = eventID.getID();
```

Comment: Please, post the code relevant to the question

Comment: done I was just adding it

Comment: that's not how you pass data between views. check this answer i gave a while ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43185945/state-is-params-is-empty-for-my-angular-js-project/43186067#43186067 it might be helpful.

Comment: shiiit , I have been trying to do it for about 3 days now ! thank you!!